# OleDbCommand is not persisted in the DB

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, oledbconnection, oledbcommand

I'm learning C# for a small project with an Access DB.

I get no error when I click on the button to run my sql statement through OleDbCommand but no row is inserted in the table though.

I think my connection is perfectly set up because I get an error if I don't use the right type for a column (e.g. insert a string in an int).
I know the button is working too because I add an action on a text which is working. Finally I know also that my query works since I have tried it directly via VS on my table.

Am I missing a step?

Here my code:

```
namespace ProjetFalk
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btn_onclick_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label12.Text = string.Empty;
            string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;data source=DBFalk.accdb";
            OleDbConnection dbconn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
            dbconn.Open();
            string dbcommand = "INSERT INTO Produit (NOM,REFERENCE) VALUES('TEST2', 'test2')"; // + TextBox_Nom.Text + "')";
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(dbcommand, dbconn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            dbconn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Please be tolerant, it's new for me. (I have read [the docs on Microsoft too for my setup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0))

Comment: Your database in the connectionstring has no path. So it is located in the same directory where your program runs. Inside a Visual Studio DEBUG session, this folder is the BIN\DEBUG one. Did you check if the database in that folder has your changes? Also check if you copy the database from the project folder to the run folder every time you start your program (Property Copy To Output Directory on the database file)

Comment: I changed the property Copy To Output Directory to 'Always' and it works now. Thanks for the quick answer ! :)

Comment: Always seems  to be wrong for me. This means that everytime you start a session with Visual Studio the file is replaced with the copy from your project folder. Then the program runs and makes changes to the file in BIN\DEBUG. So far so good, but if you start again VS the process repeats and the file in BIN\DEBUG is overwritten and you loose the changes made in the previous session. Usually I copy the file manually the first time and then set the property to Copy Never. But, of course, your context could be different.